# Create an Access97 Linked Table from C#

Tags: ms-access, com, vba, office-automation

I have a C# WPF application that creates a couple of Access97 databases and populates with data from Sql Server. One of the databases needs to have linked tables created that link to the other database.

Does anyone know if this is possible without using DoCmd? Unfortunately, when DoCmd is run on the client's PCs (I've tried several) the app crashes immediately with no message displayed, or in the event log.

Comment: Even if only for testing purposes, can you try having your app create an Access_2000/2003 database (JET_4) instead of an Access_97 database (JET_3.5)? The Access_97 file format has long since been deprecated, and the Access Database Engine versions for Access_2013+ no longer work with that file format *at all*.